# Does Pathfinder have a Saint template?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-templates

Is there something like the Saint Template from the 3.5 *Book of Exalted Deeds* in Pathfinder (3rd party stuff included)?

Comment: If you're including third party stuff, why doesn't the FR Saint Template you linked to apply?  Pathfinder and 3.5 are very compatible.

Comment: What do you want out of a "Saint template?"  The fluff?  There's dozens of holy-whatnot classes and p-classes and templates.  The exact powers?

Comment: I think I will try it this way. I choose an Aasimar, so I have Type: Outsider, Keen Vision and Damage Reduction (I will change Acid/Cold/Electro to Magic/Evil/Fire). Then I will change Crusading Magic (+2 to overcome SR) with Holy Power. Going into Bard - Arcane Striker I can change Arcane Strike with Holy Power (just 1d6 instead of 2d6-holy). I will the character develop these things over a few levels and stard as a gnome who will start with guidance, bless, virute and resistance as SLA in exchange for the gome magic. Just Amor Class, Fast Healing and Protective Aura is still missing.

Comment: Is that comment supposed to be part of your question? It actually makes it much less clear what you're asking. What is your question? Is it "How can I make a Saint-like character"?

Comment: no, if that would be sopposed to be part of the question I would have edited my question. This is rather a comment to mxyzplks question what I want. Thereupon I started to create an saint to see what I want exactley and how I could build it with the pfd sources. So THIS IS NOT PART OF THE QUESTION!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Not Really.

There's a few Templates that are sort of Good-ey, there's a few prestige classes that are saint-esque, but there's nothing with either the mechanical *whammy* or the horrifically extensive roleplaying requirements of the 3.5e *Saint* template.

A complex mixture of Pathfinder classes, spells, abilities, racial options, could produce something mechanically a bit like the Saint template's abilities, albeit slower (as there is no direct analogue and the optimizable abilities in pathfinder don't really mimic the 'defensive' nature of the saint template very well), but there is no good direct analogue.

Porting it directly might not be possible as the flat bonuses and abilities the Saint template grants (like the Vow of Poverty feat) probably look 'too powerful' to GMs with weaker mechanical understanding of the game.  Nonetheless, it's probably the only way to preserve that mixture of flavour and effect.

Comment: I'm not sure how porting it directly wouldn't be possible?  The power level and general level scope in both 3.5 and Pathfinder doesn't differ much.  Worth mentioning that an actual saint should probably be a pretty powerful being.  I also suggest removing that wording as it is misleading and you directly contradict yourself at the end of that paragraph.   You say it "might not be possible" then you say "it's probably the only way."

Comment: @LegendaryDude  - The GM decides what goes in the game.  Most pathfinder games do not blanketly allow 3.5e or PF 3rd party material.  This question is also not about whether or not Saint can be ported into PF - it's about whether there is anything like Saint in PF.  The last paragraph is a comment on whether a GM following the normal PF mode would allow the Saint template - my guess is that a lot would not.

Comment: You're assuming the querent isn't the GM in his game (there is no information provided to indicate either way), and the question specifically says "3rd party stuff included."  It just sounds like you're adding context that isn't there and may not apply.

Comment: @JackLesnie I feel that your last paragraph too much suggests that a GM would be *right* to ban it *based on the Vow of Poverty feat*, which is just massively inaccurate. Your use of “weaker mechanical understanding of the game” gives a clue that you don’t agree, but I think this answer would be much better without the reference to the horrific Vow of Poverty feat. Saint **is** a rather-powerful template, but it’s definitely **not** because of Vow of Poverty.